# Should Occam's razor be used in judging hypothetical cosmological theories?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Should Occam's razor be used in making preference between cosmological theories, which in order to fit in new experimental results, introduce hypothetical concepts, such as dark matter and dark energy, and cosmological theories (such as, for example, https://themindguild.com/new-theory-claims-universe-works-without-dark-matter-dark-energy/ https://phys.org/news/2021-06-dark-real-misunderstood-gravity.html), which try to modify existent theories without introducing new hypothetical concepts?

Comment: Occam's razor is a very very general "common sense" principle: it is not a "rule" that can dictate how to discovery/test/refute scientific theories.

Comment: What should be razed? Dark matter and dark energy?

Comment: @Deschele Schilder Yes, possibly...

Comment: But other things are introduced. Instead of dark matter and energy a space is introduced on the boundary of the universe. All that happens in our space is a shadow of processes going on at the boundsry (AdS/CFT correspondence).

Comment: @Deschele Schilder What you have mentioned could also be discussed within my broadly outlined questions.

Comment: The theory of emergent gravity has been proposed by my fellow countryman Verlinde. His claim is disproven though by observations on the Bullet Cluster. He says dark matter and normal matter are tied together (I never understood why he got 2 million prize for it; on the news it was announced that he discovered a new explanation of gravity) The observations show that dark matter and normal matter are two different things. It could be though that the extra force is just magnetic in Nature. The sun has an electric current and these can cause a magnetic force in the magnetic field of the galaxy.

Comment: There is also the possibility that dark matter is an influence from another parallel universe from which only gravity can escape. I think dark matter is just made up of primordial black holes. A parallel universe merely shifts the problem. Dark energy can just be a negative curvature of space. Galaxies (or particles) just move away from each other. No expansion required.

Comment: https://researchoutreach.org/articles/hydrogens-second-flavour-solution-to-dark-matter/